# Methods for solving the inequality $ \frac{x+2}{3x+4} \ge \frac{x+1}{x+2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have the following inequality from a textbook:

$$
\frac{x+2}{3x+4} \ge \frac{x+1}{x+2}
$$

My initial strategy to set it $\ge 0$ was:

1. Multiplying both sides by $x +2$:
   $$
   \frac{(x+2)^2}{3x+4} \ge x + 1
   $$
2. Subtracting $x +1$ from both sides:
   $$
   \frac{(x+2)^2}{3x+4} - x - 1 \ge 0
   $$

But I must of done something wrong here, as it's completely different from the textbook (and has a different solution once its all played out).

The textbook:

1. Subtracted $\frac{x+1}{x+2}$ from both sides:
   $$
   \frac{x + 2}{3x + 4} - \frac{x + 1}{x + 2} \ge 0
   $$
2. Combined the terms using the LCM.

When the 2 different LHS functions are graphed, they are completely different.

Did I do something wrong, or am I misunderstanding the results?

Comment: Do you know that $(x+2)>0$? If it's negative, the inequality will change from $\ge$ to $\le$

Comment: You can't multiply by $x+2$ both sides because you don't know if it's positive or negative (if it's negative you have to flip the inequality)

Comment: The proper way is to move both fractions to one side, combine them then use interval method for rational inequalities. When you multiply both sides of inequality or equation by an expression containing a variable, bad thing happen because it's value is unknown. What if it's zero?

Comment: Besides the inequality itself, you have the restrictions : $3x+4 \neq 0$ and $x+2 \neq 0$

Comment: It's fine to multiply by $x+2$ so long as you consider both $x>-2$ and $x<-2$ and adjust the inequality accordingly. But to address your actual question: you shouldn't expect the graphs to be the same. Consider a simpler problem like $\frac x2>3$. You could subtract $3$ to get $\frac x2 - 3 > 0$, but you could also multiply by $2$, then subtract $6$ to get $x - 6 > 0$. These have the same set of solutions in terms of $x$, but the graph of the LHS is different.

Comment: That makes complete sense, I never considered that what I multiplied by has a variable in it. 

That still leaves me with one question (which I can ask in another thread if needed). Why do both LHS functions graph completely different? If you have an equation with multiple ways of moving things around, and it reaches a point where the RHS is 0 from different means; my (wrong) assumption is that you would get the same LHS each time, but maybe a few steps removed (factoring, etc.). Edit: Theophile gave me the simpler problem I was looking for to disprove my assumption.

Comment: They look different because of multiplying by a non-constant term, $x+2$. In my example above, from $x-6>0$ you could multiply both sides by $(x-6)^2$ to get $(x-6)^3 > 0$. (Note that the inequality is preserved because $(x-6)^2$ is always nonnegative.) Certainly the graphs of $x-6$ and $(x-6)^3$ are very different! The *set of solutions* to $x-6>0$ and $(x-6)^3>0$ is the same, though; namely, $x>6$.

Comment: A more dramatic example: consider $x^2+1>0$ and $\cos x + 2>0$. These are obviously very different functions on the LHS, but they have the same set of solutions (they are true for all $x$). You could manipulate the former into the latter by first dividing by $x^2+1$ then multiplying by $\cos x + 2$; these operations preserve the inequalities because you're multiplying or dividing by a positive amount. This shows that you really can't expect the graph of the LHS to look the same if you manipulate it, even if the set of solutions is the same.

Comment: You wouldn't expect the two to be equal, you'd expect your left hand side to be $x+2$ times the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a very long answer because I thought it was important for you to see the steps behind how to do the problem.*
$\frac{x+2}{3x+4} \geq \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ when $-2<x\leq -\frac{3}{2}$ AND $-\frac{4}{3}<x\leq0$.

You have the right idea in wanting to get all of the variables on one side of the inequality and a zero on the other side. However, as several people commented you can run into trouble multiplying both sides by $(x+2)$. Without knowing if $(x+2)\geq 0$, you won't know whether to flip the inequality.

Your textbook goes about solving the problem in the following way:
$$\frac{x+2}{3x+4} \geq \frac{x+1}{x+2}$$
$$\frac{x+2}{3x+4} - \frac{x+1}{x+2} \geq 0$$
They then multiply both fractions by 1 in the form of the other fraction's denominator to create a common denominator:
$$\left(\frac{x+2}{x+2}\right)\frac{x+2}{3x+4} - \left(\frac{3x+4}{3x+4}\right)\frac{x+1}{x+2} \geq 0$$
$$\frac{(x+2)(x+2)}{(x+2)(3x+4)} - \frac{(x+1)(3x+4)}{(x+2)(3x+4)} \geq 0$$
$$\frac{(x+2)(x+2)-(x+1)(3x+4)}{(x+2)(3x+4)}$$
The numerator is then expanded to get:
$$\frac{x^2 +4x+4-3x^2 -3x-4x-4}{(x+2)(3x+4)} \geq 0$$
$$\frac{-2x^2-3x}{(x+2)(3x+4)}\geq0$$
We can then factor the numerator to get:
$$\frac{-x(2x+3)}{(3x+4)(x+2)}\geq 0$$

So now the question is what does this tell us about the values of x? Let's look at the numerator first. Where is $-x(2x+3)\geq0$? Well the zero property of multiplication tells us that $-x(2x+3)=0$ when $-x=0$ or $2x+3=0$, when $x=0$ or $x=-\frac{3}{2}$. So what about values of $x$ that will result in a positive numerator? Based on how multiplication of negatives works, we know that $-x$ and $(2x+3)$ need to be either be both positive or both negative. Obviously $-x$ will take on the opposite sign of whatever value is substituted in, but $(2x+3)$ requires closer inspection.

First let's look at $x$ values where $2x+3>0$. Subtracting 3 gives $2x>-3$ which becomes $x>-\frac{3}{2}$ with division by 2. So for $x>-\frac{3}{2}$, $(2x+3)>0$. Now, which values in this range make $-x>0$? Simple division by -1 tells us that all the values where $x<0$ will give us our positive value. So, this tells us that both $-x$ and $(2x+3)$ will be positive for $-\frac{3}{2}<x<0$.

Now, let's look at $x$ values where $2x+3<0$. Simplification gives us $x<-\frac{3}{2}$. Now, which of the values in this range make $-x<0$? Well those would be the values where $x>0$. But it's impossible to have $x>0$ AND $x<-\frac{3}{2}<0$. So we know that this case is not feasible.

Okay, so just from the numerator we have that $-x(2x+3)>0$ for $-\frac{3}{2}<x<0$ and that $-x(2x+3)=0$ for $x=0$ and $x=-\frac{3}{2}$. So these can be combined to give us that the numerator $-x(2x+3)\geq0$ for $-\frac{3}{2}\leq x\leq0$.

Unfortunately, we aren't done yet since we also have to consider the denominator. When we are dealing with rational functions we must check for asymptotes. Since we are only concerned with finding the domain of this function, we care about vertical asymptotes. To find vertical asymptotes, we are looking for $x$ values that would make the denominator of our rational function equal to zero, $(x+2)(3x+4)=0$ in this case. Fortunately, in this example we can just set each factor equal to zero and solve for $x$.

$x+2=0$ gives us a vertical asymptote at $x=-2$. $3x+4=0$ becomes $3x=-4$ which gives us a vertical asymptote at $x=-\frac{4}{3}$. Now that we know where there are vertical asymptotes, we should check to see if either of our asymptotes falls into our domain of $-\frac{3}{2}\leq x\leq0$ that we identified earlier. Notice that $-\frac{3}{2}<-\frac{4}{3}<0$. We now have to look at what happens to the values of our function on either side of the vertical asymptote.

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| -1.3 | 7.429 |
| -1.33 | 62.492 |
| -1.333 | 667.499 |
| ... | ... |
| -1.334 | -332.498 |
| -1.34 | -32.485 |

As we approach $-\frac{4}{3}$ from the right the $y$ value increases rapidly towards infinity. As we approach $-\frac{4}{3}$ from the left the $y$ value decreases rapidly towards negative infinity. Since we only want positive $y$ values, we must now adjust our domain to be $-\frac{4}{3}<x\leq0$.

Though the $x$ values between $-\frac{4}{3}$ and $-\frac{3}{2}$ are negative ($y=-0.12$ when $x=-1.49$), we should still look more closely at $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ since it makes $\frac{-x(2x+3)}{(3x+4)(x+2)}=0$. We have just seen that the right side of $x=-\frac{3}{2}$ yields negative values (and therefore is not relevant), but what about the left side? Earlier we saw that $x<-\frac{3}{2}$ resulted in a negative numerator value. However, if $x<-\frac{3}{2}$ also results in a negative denominator value then $\frac{-x(2x+3)}{(3x+4)(x+2)}\geq0$. Let's take a look.

In order to best demonstrate whether $x<-\frac{3}{2}$ produces a positive value let's randomly choose $x=-\frac{7}{4}$.
$$\frac{-\left(-\frac{7}{4}\right)\left(2\left(-\frac{7}{4}\right)+3\right)}{\left(3\left(-\frac{7}{4}\right)+4\right)\left(-\frac{7}{4}+2\right)}$$
$$\frac{\frac{7}{4}\left(-\frac{7}{2}+3\right)}{\left(-\frac{21}{4}+4\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
We only care whether the result is positive or negative, so for simplicity we can reduce each expression to a positive or negative:
$$\frac{(\text{positive})(\text{negative})}{(\text{negative})(\text{positive})}$$
$$\frac{\text{negative}}{\text{negative}}=\text{positive}>0$$

Okay so what does this tell us? In addition to $-\frac{4}{3}<x\leq0$ we have another part of the domain that meets the criteria! We now know that $x\leq -\frac{3}{2}$ also produces $\frac{-x(2x+3)}{(3x+4)(x+2)}\geq0$. So now we must consider our other vertical asymptote ($x=-2$) since it now falls in the domain of interest. Like before, we will look at what happens to the values of our function on either side of the vertical asymptote.

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| -1.9 | 8.941 |
| -1.99 | 98.995 |
| -1.999 | 999.000 |
| ... | ... |
| -2.001 | -1001 |
| -2.01 | -100.995 |
| -2.1 | -10.9565 |

Once again, our $y$ values approach infinity as $x$ approaches $-2$ from the right side and $y$ approaches negative infinity as $x$ approaches $-2$ from the left side. So we only want the right side. Now we know that $\frac{-x(2x+3)}{(3x+4)(x+2)}\geq0$ when $-2<x\leq -\frac{3}{2}$.

**So $\frac{x+2}{3x+4} \geq \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ when $-2<x\leq -\frac{3}{2}$ AND $-\frac{4}{3}<x\leq0$.**

Extra note:

The left side of both asymptotes resulted in negative numbers. We did not need to consider whether these values would eventually become positive due to the presence of a horizontal asymptote at $y=-\frac{2}{3}$. As $x$ approaches negative infinity (the area where $x<-2$) the $y$ values will be bounded above at $-\frac{2}{3}$ by this asymptote and therefore will never be positive.